# Shortcut to add code to each javascript page (with variable jquery selector)

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code, shortcut

I have 200 javascript files and there is a code like this in them.

```
    $('#//Variable// tbody').on('click', '[id*=selectbtn]', function () {
        var data = dataTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        _modalManager.setResult(data);
        _modalManager.close();
    });
```

I need to add code like below to each page. Is there a short way to do this?
I am using visual studio code as editor.

```
    $('#//Variable// tbody').on('click', '[id*=selectbtn]', function () {
        var data = dataTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        _modalManager.setResult(data);
        _modalManager.close();
    });

    
    $('#//Variable// tbody').on('dblclick',"tr", function () {
        var data = dataTable.row($(this)).data();
        _modalManager.setResult(data);
        _modalManager.close();
    });
```

I don't know how to do it as the jquery selector is variable on each page.

Comment: Seems like one should use a common class.....

Comment: As above, as an example, set a class on the `tr`, eg <tr class='selectable'>` then `$(document).on("dblclick", "tr.selectable", function() ...`

Comment: you should seriously consider a redesign of the application